# Make file: Pattern Rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am confused with the usage of pattern rules in a make file.

After going through a lot of websites and resources, I have found that the following makefile can be used to generate executable for every source file in the directory.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
LDFLAGS = -lpthread

all: $(basename $(wildcard *.c))

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    rm -rf $(basename $(wildcard *.c))
```

I understand that "$(basename $(wildcard *.c))" returns the file names of .c files without extension. This is in turn being used as dependencies for the target all.

However, I don't understand the follwing: How does the % operator map to the dependencies mentioned in the target 'all'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

make maintains a dictionary of pattern rules.  When make wants to build a target, if there's no explicit rule for the target, then it will go through the dictionary of pattern rules to find a rule that will build the target.

Here, the target pattern is `%` which will match anything (the `%` is a wildcard, kind of like the shell's `*` globbing character).  So every target make wants to build will match this pattern.  Then make looks to see if the prerequisite exists or can be built, replacing the stem (the text that matches `%`) in the prerequisite(s).

So if make wants to build `foo`, it matches this rule with a stem of `foo`, and then if it can find or build `foo.c` (because `%.c` with a stem of `foo` results in `foo.c`) then that rule matches, and make will use it.

If not, make will keep looking through the rest of its dictionary of implicit rules.  If none of them match, it will say "No rule to make 'foo'" and fail.

Comment: In general, "match anything" rules in make are dangerous and should be avoided; since they can match anything they could result in make doing a LOT of work, and there are special restrictions on them to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: Hey @MadScientist, thankyou for the response. I wasnt aware that make has "implicit rules" and "it will go through the dictionary of pattern rules to find a rule that will build the target."
Now, the make file makes more sense.

Comment: In general the GNU make manual is the best place to go to learn about make.  Web pages, blog posts, etc. may or may not be useful or even correct.  For example: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html